# How Close an MT5 Order from Python?

Tags: python, mql5, metatrader5

I'm trying to send orders from a python script to my MT5 terminal via the MT5-python API.

I can open a position but how can I close it from Python mt5-API?

I open a BUY ticket it like this:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5 
lot = 0.1
request = {
"action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
"symbol": symbol,
"volume": lot,
"type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY,
"price": price,
.....
"type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC,
 "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN,
}

enter copoint = mt5.symbol_info(symbol).point
```

But what command and form to send a "close"?

Find more info:
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13):

an easier way to do it

```
mt5.Close(symbol,ticket=ticket)
```

note: `ticket` is the same as `position_id`

Comment: It is better when you have hedge enabled as well. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm confused. Where is the mt5.Close() function?  I don't see that anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

The structure of the order is the same, Only that during close, you have to specify the position_id that you got from the result object returned by the first order. And obviously, if closing a buy order, the close request is a sell order.
Here is the code that you could use to do both a buy and sell.

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5


ea_magic_number = 9986989 # if you want to give every bot a unique identifier

def get_info(symbol):
    '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5symbolinfo_py
    '''
    # get symbol properties
    info=mt5.symbol_info(symbol)
    return info

def open_trade(action, symbol, lot, sl_points, tp_points, deviation):
    '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py
    '''
    # prepare the buy request structure
    symbol_info = get_info(symbol)

    if action == 'buy':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask
    elif action =='sell':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
    point = mt5.symbol_info(symbol).point

    buy_request = {
        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "volume": lot,
        "type": trade_type,
        "price": price,
        "sl": price - sl_points * point,
        "tp": price + tp_points * point,
        "deviation": deviation,
        "magic": ea_magic_number,
        "comment": "sent by python",
        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC, # good till cancelled
        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN,
    }
    # send a trading request
    result = mt5.order_send(buy_request)        
    return result, buy_request 

def close_trade(action, buy_request, result, deviation):
    '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py
    '''
    # create a close request
    symbol = buy_request['symbol']
    if action == 'buy':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask
    elif action =='sell':
        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
    position_id=result.order
    lot = buy_request['volume']

    close_request={
        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "volume": lot,
        "type": trade_type,
        "position": position_id,
        "price": price,
        "deviation": deviation,
        "magic": ea_magic_number,
        "comment": "python script close",
        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC, # good till cancelled
        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN,
    }
    # send a close request
    result=mt5.order_send(close_request)


# This is how I would execute the order
result, buy_request = open_trade('buy', 'USDJPY', 0.1, 50, 50, 10)
close_trade('sell', buy_request, result, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

mt5.Close(symbol,ticket=ticket), and pay attention the ticket is a number not a string type.