# sending order to open a position via MetaTrader5 python module and nothing happens

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, mql5, metatrader5

I followed [Metatrader5 python documentation](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971841/how-close-an-mt5-order-from-python#) answer in stack overflow

I try to open a sell position:

> ```
> import MetaTrader5 as mt5
>
>
> ea_magic_number = 9986989 # if you want to give every bot a unique identifier
>
> def get_info(symbol):
>     '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5symbolinfo_py
>     '''
>     # get symbol properties
>     info=mt5.symbol_info(symbol)
>     return info
>
> def open_trade(action, symbol, lot, sl_points, tp_points, deviation):
>     '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py
>     '''
>     # prepare the buy request structure
>     symbol_info = get_info(symbol)
>
>     if action == 'buy':
>         trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY
>         price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask
>     elif action =='sell':
>         trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
>         price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
>     point = mt5.symbol_info(symbol).point
>
>     buy_request = {
>         "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
>         "symbol": symbol,
>         "volume": lot,
>         "type": trade_type,
>         "price": price,
>         "sl": price - sl_points * point,
>         "tp": price + tp_points * point,
>         "deviation": deviation,
>         "magic": ea_magic_number,
>         "comment": "sent by python",
>         "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC, # good till cancelled
>         "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN,
>     }
>     # send a trading request
>     result = mt5.order_send(buy_request)        
>     return result, buy_request 
>
> def close_trade(action, buy_request, result, deviation):
>     '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py
>     '''
>     # create a close request
>     symbol = buy_request['symbol']
>     if action == 'buy':
>         trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY
>         price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask
>     elif action =='sell':
>         trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
>         price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
>     position_id=result.order
>     lot = buy_request['volume']
>
>     close_request={
>         "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
>         "symbol": symbol,
>         "volume": lot,
>         "type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL,
>         "position": position_id,
>         "price": price,
>         "deviation": deviation,
>         "magic": ea_magic_number,
>         "comment": "python script close",
>         "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC, # good till cancelled
>         "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN,
>     }
>     # send a close request
>     result=mt5.order_send(close_request)
>
>
> # This is how I would execute the order
> result, buy_request = open_trade('buy', 'USDJPY', 0.1, 50, 50, 10)
> close_trade('sell', buy_request, result, 10)
> ```

Nothing happens and there is no reaction in applications terminal. I also check Trade and History section  in Metatrader5 to find some related information but I find out nothing.

how can I monitor the logs in Metatrader5 to debug the code and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MetaTrader algo trading must be ON in order to make a buy/sell position.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for people that reach this topic and for whom the Algo trading button was ON and nothing was happening when sending orders.

In my case, it was because I was setting the 'volume' of the request as an integer, and it must be a float. No error was being shown, no sign of life, order_send(...) returned None and that was it. Just cast'ed the incoming value to float and it worked.

This is not the case of the question author, but I hope it helps some venturing soul in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed:

`"type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_RETURN`

to :

`"type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_IOC`

and then It works for me.

I'm using python version 3.10